# Hazelcast and MultiMap type working with "eviction policy"

Tags: hazelcast

I want to keep one List of Long types, which depends on other entity, this List is set with user ids, short time after, I want to remove that list, but there may be many entries with Lists like that.

Therefore, my first attempt has been working with MultiMap type like this < Long, List of Longs  >, but, unfortunately, MultiMap has not been implemented with eviction policy. The next step, was to try to implement one distributed scheduled task to remove all that set of lists, and to achieve that, I found some methods that looks fine for achieve it in ExecutionService.

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/spi/ExecutionService.html

But I don't know the good way to do, or even if it is possible.

Finally, I try to achieve this behaviour working with IMap, but I have one problem with this aproximation, each time I want to remove or add one new Long id to the list, I have to get the full list from the server, and is sure that this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: I am not sure how it works with Hazelcast (probably same) but cross-cache querying with Coherence causes nasty deadlocks, usually in production code when you scale out.

Comment: Then MarianP, what is your conclusion?, Are you saying Hazelcast is a bad choice?, or any in-memory data grid are?, Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want eviction on all of the records within the multimap or within the longmaps?

Answer (score 2):

I needed a similar approach to what you wanted. Here's the solution that I used:

1. Use an Hazelcast IMap and a MultiMap. The MultiMap will contain the values of your "Set", using the same Key value that you use for the IMap;
2. Define an EntryExpiredListener for your IMap. This way, when an entry expires for your IMap, the related MultiMap Entry will also be removed, meaning that in the end the MultiMap will use the same eviction configurations that were defined for the IMap eg.:

   ```
   static class MyEntryExpiredListener implements EntryExpiredListener {
   @Override
   public void entryExpired(EntryEvent event) {
   // Here you'll remove the entry with the same key in the MultiMap:
   getMultiMap().remove(event.getKey());
   }
   }
   ```

   ...

   ```
   MyEntryExpiredListener entryExpiredListener = new MyEntryExpiredListener();
   ```

   ...

   ```
   HazelcastMap.addEntryListener(entryExpiredListener, false);
   ```

You can also define the MultiMap to behave as a Set, as defined by the configuration property (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.3/manual/html-single/index.html#multimap):

```
<multimap name="MY_MULTIMAP">
    <value-collection-type>SET</value-collection-type>
 </multimap>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about mixing IMap and IList to achieve your goal?

```
IMap<String, String> mapping = hazelcastInstance.getMap("mappings");
String reference = mapping.get("someListIdentifier");
IList<Long> longs = hazelcastInstance.getList(reference);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response noctarius, but, I don't found by any way where IList have any method to implement the eviction politic neither... Would be bad performance put many entries, maybe millions in one IMap namespace?. I Think this could work fine...

Comment: Oh yeah I see... uh you would still have to iterate them. Good question. Let me think about it... Not yet sure how to attack that problem.